# Error in receiving file

Tags: c++, c, file, file-upload, recv

I have this code:

```
while (1) {
    char buffer[4096];
    memset(buffer,0,4096);
    int bytes_read = recv(client_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer),0);
    if (bytes_read == 0)
        break;
    if (bytes_read < 0) {
        std::cout<< "Error "<<endl;
    }
    void *p = buffer;
    int dest;
    dest=open("/root/hello.txt",O_WRONLY);
    while (bytes_read > 0) {
        int bytes_written = send(dest, buffer, bytes_read,0);
        if (bytes_written <= 0) {
            std::cout<< "Error2 "<<endl;
        }
        bytes_read -= bytes_written;
        p += bytes_written;
    }
}
```

I receive the file correctly.
The program goes in loop where the cout is "Error2", so the send returns -1.
The problem is to write the file in a new file descriptor, in this case the variable called `dest`.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing socket fd as first parameter to [`send`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/send.html)?

Comment: Why are you using `send` to write to a regular file? (Especially in C++?!) And why aren't you checking `errno` after `send` returns `-1`? It seems easier to ask `perror` than to ask StackOverflow . . .

Comment: Your loop keeps re-opening the file, each time getting a new descriptor opened to the beginning of the file. And it never closes it, so it leaks descriptors.

Comment: @another.anon.coward: Yes, the send man page says so

Comment: You should use p instead of buffer in the send(). Also you cannot increment a void pointer, so it needs to be a char*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the manual-page for `send(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/send.2.html), it can only write to a socket, not to a regular file; if you had checked `errno` (using e.g. [`perror`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/perror.3.html)), you would have seen that it gets set to `ENOTSOCK`. You should always see *what* error is being set, otherwise debugging is just shooting in the dark.

Also, since this is C++, I really think you should use C++-style I/O (`std::ofstream` and so on) to write to a regular file.

Answer (score 0):

Check the return value of

```
dest=open("/root/hello.txt",O_WRONLY);
```

It should be a positive integer; everything else indicates an error. My guess is that the file can't be opened for whatever reason.

Comment: The val returned is -1.
I have tried also with O_RDWR.
How can I solve this?

Comment: @user1056635: What does it set `errno` to?

Comment: Well...I've just resolved the problem using an appropriate function for C++, ofstream.